# Cannot read property 'filter' of null - Jasmine/Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to mock the class Location, but without success

This is my jasmine file

```
providers: [
        {
          provide: Location, useClass: class {
            filter: string = 'Germany';
            getState() {
              return this.filter;
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

The error is here

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-scheduling-list',
  templateUrl: './scheduling-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scheduling-list.component.scss'],
})
export class SchedulingListComponent implements OnInit {

  schedulingFilter: SchedulingRequest;

  constructor(private location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.schedulingFilter = (this.location.getState() as any).filter;
  }
  
  //nothing important
```

How do i mock correctly in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

the function `getState()` returns `filter` which contains `Germany`(a string).
you can't do `getState().filter` that would be the same as `"Germany".filter`

your code should be

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.schedulingFilter = (this.location.getState() as any);
}
```